# What API levels can Chromebooks run on?

Tags: android, api, chromebook, android-api-levels

I am looking to develop an app that will run on Chromebooks only. (Will not be published on the Play Store though)

I would like to use certain features available in API Level 26 (Oreo) But my question is can you compare the API levels with Chromebooks, since the API Levels are based on the Android OS Version.

How does one go about finding what API Level Chromebooks can run on.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

> Will not be published on the Play Store though

Unless you are going to put the Chromebooks in developer mode, you have no choice but to distribute the app via the Play Store, at least at the present time. There is no "sideloading" option otherwise.

> How does one go about finding what API Level Chromebooks can run on.

Write an app that you run on a Chromebook that logs the value of `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`. In my last test — run a few days ago — Chrome OS has a `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` value of 25.

Comment: Thank you very much. The app I'm creating is for personal use so it will indeed by put into developer mode. :)